# Filter .tree data with .csv file.

Tags: csv, tree, bioinformatics

I am working with a massive .Tree file and I am looking for a way to parse it and trim it based on a .csv file. I have a file that labels the roots and branches in a .csv format that chooses the ones I want. Keep in mind this is a massive .tree so the interactive view in iTOL does not work and most GUI's will not work as the tree is massive.

Comment: look into ete2 for biopython. It will allow you to parse the tree in newick format cull parts of the tree based on your csv file. Should be trivial :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [newick_utils](http://cegg.unige.ch/newick_utils%20newick_utils). You can trim unwanted branches with nw_prune or extract a subtree with nw_clade.